# Running docker Ubuntu image on Debian environment

Tags: docker, lxc, lxc-docker

Just started using `Docker` and have some questions regarding `linux` containers.

How can I run `Ubuntu` images on a `Debian` host? Or it is just a name of image called 'Ubuntu' that actually use Debian environment?

```
# cat /proc/version

Linux version 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1~bpo70+1 (2014-12-08)

# docker run -i -t ubuntu

root@bcade5ce3b94:/# cat /proc/version

Linux version 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1~bpo70+1 (2014-12-08)
```

What about the filesystem? Does it use the same installed components or a new fs architecture that just depends on the kernel?

Maybe there is some good articles about the subject you can share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In docker all images use the same kernel - that is why overhead is minimal - virtualization layer is very thin. All files in ubuntu image from ubuntu, but any image will give you the same output of uname -a, as it is the same kernel.

```
$ docker run --rm -ti  ubuntu 
root@318f07af2ca7:/# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

You don't see host filesystem inside of container unless you will map some directory. The idea of container that it is running in the same way on any host - doesn't matter what installed there - you need only docker.

Comment: So i am just running Ubuntu on a same kernel that uses Debian ?

Comment: @dima.h yes - ubuntu, centos, gentoo use host kernel (Debian in your case).

Comment: i see that ubuntu is based on debian but the centos and gentoo is not ... how can they use debian kernel ? is it compatible ?

Comment: @dima.h yes, it will be very rare case when something is not working, see an answer here for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945109/what-will-be-impacted-for-compiling-code-in-different-kernel-in-docker