# Docker: Mixing distros - any disadvantage?

Tags: docker

I am running a RHEL 7 server and I am deploying containers using docker. Since you need to have RHEL servers and containers registered with RHN, I am now thinking of using centos7 docker images rather than RHEL7 ones, to avoid the RHN hassles.

Can anybody see any downside to doing it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the kernel is the same you can use any distro available: [Why docker has ability to run different linux distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444099/why-docker-has-ability-to-run-different-linux-distribution).

For example many projects are moving to [Alpine Linux](http://www.alpinelinux.org/) because it give you the ability to build very small images: see [Docker Official Images are Moving to Alpine Linux](https://www.brianchristner.io/docker-is-moving-to-alpine-linux/).

Comment: Thanks for the links :) I was thinking that there might some security enhancements, etc. in RHEL that is not present in CentOS or Alpine. Should that influence the decision on the distro to run in a container?

Comment: The security is mainly handled by the host kernel running your process : https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/. When I choose a distro I want up to date packages (security), none unnecessary packages (reduce attack surface), lightweight (reduce bandwidth)... Each point is influenced by the distribution.