# one compatibility issue about docker

Tags: linux, docker

It is known that the docker is a virtualized technology  based on Linux kernel, and Windows images can not be run on docker. So when I run docker daemon on centos6.5, does it matter  starting  a container run on the images of centos7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the relationship between the docker host OS and the container base image OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786209/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-docker-host-os-and-the-container-base-image)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't matter very much.  The docker image provides the filesystem for your container, while your host os provides the kernel.  The only way it could wind up mattering is if the process you are running requires some kernel feature that is not present in the kernel being run on your host system.

You can run docker images based off of all sorts of linux distros without issue.  Alpine linux has become pretty popular recently, for example.