# Since docker shares host kernel, why most docker images contain the kernel stuff?

Tags: docker

As someone answered the relationship between docker image and host:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859958/1516361

I'm wondering why the image of docker still contains kernel stuff (kernel image, .dtb files, etc.)? Except making it possible to run on non-Linux host OS (uses virtualbox instead, so it needs a bootable kernel), so what if the host kernel is much different with the image attempts to simulate?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not