# Do Docker Linux Images Contain Kernels?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-containers

If so, wouldn't there be overhead if, say, I install a Debian image which contains a specific version of a Linux Kernel? Now you have a container with a Kernel, on top of another kernel (the docker host's kernel). Or am I missing something?

Or does the docker image have the kernel stripped out some how?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859958/6309

Answer (score 2):

Docker images do not contain kernels, but they could soon. That's why Docker aquired Unikernel not long ago.

Source and further Information: http://techcrunch.com/2016/01/21/docker-acquires-unikernel-systems-as-it-looks-beyond-containers/