# What are the problems with running Docker containers where the Linux kernel version of the base image differs from the OS kernel version?

Tags: docker

I use Elasticsearch via Docker, and I see that the recent version of the Elasticsearch (7.13.2) Docker image [uses `centos:8` as the base image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).

Is it possible/a good idea to run Docker containers with a base image that is different to the operating system on which Docker Engine is installed? for example:

1. Install Docker Engine on `CentOS 7.6` (or `Ubuntu 20.04`)
2. Start a Docker container from an image based on Centos 8

If this works, is there anything I should be aware of?

Looking at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859958/3114742), it would seem to me that this shouldn't be a problem so long as the Linux kernel versions are the same between the base image and the OS. But I assume that is not the case for `CentOS 7.6` vs `CentOS 8`.

What would be the concern WRT to a mismatched Linux kernel version for a Docker container's base image vs the OS?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable answer... I take it to mean that it may or may not work depending on what the image is. So it's much better to use use a matched kernel version

Comment: Yeah, it takes [years](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.5-Kills-SYSCTL-SYSCALL) for a deprecated system call to actually get removed, so for most purposes, this should be a non-issue

Comment: The container doesn't have its own kernel, so there's no "matching" there.

Comment: A match between the version specified in the base image, and the os version.